# Adding new objects to a list within a loop [Java]

Tags: java, pointers

I'm trying to parse an XML file into java, specifically into a list of CD objects, and I have the following code.

```
public class XMLParser {

    public ArrayList<CD> prs(String filePath) {
        ArrayList<CD> CDList = new ArrayList<CD>();
        ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> artists = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> genres = new ArrayList<String>();
        ...
        //correctly gets the lists titles, artists, and genres
        ...
        for(int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
            CD cd = new CD(titles.get(i), artists.get(i), genres.get(i));
            CDList.add(cd);
        }
        //flag
        return CDList;
    }
}
```

At "flag" we have a list of n elements, each of which is exactly the same. During the loop, I know that the CDs being added are correct, and have titles.get(i) etc. as their fields. For this reason I'm pretty sure it's a pointer error of some sort.

I instantiate a new CD during every iteration of the for loop, so I don't understand why it keeps pointing back to a single object rather than creating new objects in memory. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us your `CD` class code

Comment: @Katie, you said that you get the Correct Titels, Artist and Genres... So i think your constructor must make some mistakes or something like this! If you add in the Loop a System.out.println(titles,artists,genres), do you get some Output there ? It is also Important to get some more informations about the CD Class aswell...

Comment: Your `CD` code doesn't use static fields does it?

Comment: Oops, I just realized I did use static fields. Thanks!

Comment: @Katie Side note on code quality: bad naming for your method - what is "prs" supposed to tell the reader what the method will do? Besides: avoid doing "all things" in a simple method. A method should do one thing only; it should not create many different data structures, fill them, glue them together ...